# How to highlight a button until giving a valid value to the spinner?

Tags: java, android

I am new in android, for practise i took 4 spinners and 1 button. Spinner 1 value decide spinner 2 values and so on and i want to show some toast on click on button with all spinners values.
If value of all spinners are default then button will not highlight , whenever i give the valid value in all spinners button will be highlighted automatically. 
Help me out, what should i do to get this point ??

Here is my code........

```
sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            country = String.valueOf(sp1.getSelectedItem());
            if (country.equals("USA")) {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states_usa);
                adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp2.setAdapter(adapter1);
            }else if (country.equals("India")){
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states_india);
                adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp2.setAdapter(adapter1);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            state = String.valueOf(sp2.getSelectedItem());
            if (state.equalsIgnoreCase("California")) {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cities_california);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp3.setAdapter(adapter2);
            } else if (state.equals("Rajasthan")) {
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cities_rajasthan);
                adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp3.setAdapter(adapter2);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            city = String.valueOf(sp3.getSelectedItem());
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3;
            switch (city) {
                case "Los Angeles":
                    adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, areas_losangeles);
                    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    sp4.setAdapter(adapter3);
                    break;
                case "San Francisco":
                    adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, areas_sanfrancisco);
                    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    sp4.setAdapter(adapter3);
                    break;
                case "Jaipur":
                    adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, areas_jaipur);
                    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    sp4.setAdapter(adapter3);
                    break;
                case "Ajmer":
                    adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, areas_ajmer);
                    adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    sp4.setAdapter(adapter3);
                    break;
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    resultButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!sp1.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Country") && !sp2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("State")
                    && !sp3.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("City") && !sp4.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Area"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Country : "+sp1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"\n"+
                        "State : "+ sp2.getSelectedItem().toString()+"\n"+
                        "City : "+sp3.getSelectedItem().toString()+"\n"+
                        "Area : "+sp4.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                resultButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Customize the spinner adapter with custom layout. Use TextView in the layout and set error on tap of button click listener.

```
button.setOnClickListener{

    TextView spinnerText= (TextView)yourSpinner.getSelectedView();
    spinnerText.setError("");
    spinnerText.setTextColor(Color.RED);//It will just to highlight that this is an error
    spinnerText.setText("your actual error text");

}
```

I hope it works!